# 2-dimensional arrays not assigning values

Tags: c#

So I have a two-dimensional array, or an array of arrays, that looks like this:

```
public static double[][] arrayOfArrays = {Jan,
                                             Feb,
                                             Mar,
                                             Apr,
                                             May,
                                             Jun,
                                             Jul,
                                             Aug,
                                             Sep,
                                             Oct,
                                             Nov,
                                             Dec};
```

Each of those items is an array that looks like this:

```
public static double[] Jan = {Properties.Settings.Default.Jan1Costs,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan2Costs,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan3Costs,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan4Costs,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan5Cost,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan6Cost,
                                   Properties.Settings.Default.Jan7Cost};
```

I'm having some trouble assigning values to the arrays. The program compiles and all, but these two pieces of code produce different results.
Both of the arrays are in a class called Globals.

This is Method 1:

```
Globals.Oct[1] += AR * Properties.Settings.Default.MyPrice;
```

and this is Method 2:

```
Globals.arrayOfArrays[9][1] += AR * Properties.Settings.Default.MyPrice;
```

Unless I misunderstand 2D arrays, both should do the same thing, right? However, I find that Method 2 does absolutely nothing and doesn't save anything to the settings. Method 1, however, does.

I'd like to know what's stopping Method 2 from working, as I would very much like to be able to save values by using DateTime.Now.Month in the first array slot, so I don't need to have 12 if/cases for different months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working about the second method? Or what's working differently? Is there an error?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a minimal sample code? e.g. 2x2 array or something? It seems odd.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're not using nested lists over nested arrays? List<List<double>> would be a lot easier to manage, and lists are generally preferred over arrays.

Comment: With a good code example, this would be easy for many readers to help you fix. Without it, it's going to be very hard. Your general understanding seems to be correct, so likely your actual code is not like the code fragments you posted, or you've left out some important detail regarding the relationship of those fragments to each other. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @furkle No error, it just doesn't assign a value. Also, I didn't know about lists, so I will try that.

Comment: As for the relationship, could it be to do with the files? The Globals class is defined in Globals.cs, and I'm calling both Method 1 and 2 from various other files. This is the actual code I'm using, and I'm not sure what other information, aside from posting my entire project, I could give.

Answer (score 0):

Try as much not to get value from `static` variables to calculate `static` variable's value. For example why:

```
public static int i = j * 2;
public static int j = 2;
```

`i` isn't determinable, it could be `0` because default value of int (`j`) is `0`, or because the initialization of the variables reversed because some reason.

Change your class's code to:

```
//Inside your Globals.cs's class
public static double[][] arrayOfArrays;
public static double[] Jan;
... //All of your months' variables, without assignment of course.
static Globals( ) {
    Jan = {Properties.Settings.Default.Jan1Costs,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan2Costs,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan3Costs,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan4Costs,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan5Cost,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan6Cost,
           Properties.Settings.Default.Jan7Cost};
    ... //Assign here the rest months' variables
    arrayOfArrays = {Jan,
                    Feb,
                    Mar,
                    Apr,
                    May,
                    Jun,
                    Jul,
                    Aug,
                    Sep,
                    Oct,
                    Nov,
                    Dec};
}
```

So all of the `arrayOfArrays`'s arrays will be referenced to the same object as the variables in the class.